# IDE to develop mac dashboard widgets?

Tags: macos, ide, mac-dashboard-widget

What is the best IDE to develop Mac dashboard widgets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would probably be **Dashcode**, which is found here:

```
/Developer/Applications/Dashcode.app
```

assuming you have Xcode installed.

Comment: Thx a lot! I haven'f found anywhere under Xcode, but now it is OK.

Comment: Has this answer become out of date?  Is Apple supporting Dashcode?

Comment: Dashcode was discontinued years ago (around Xcode 4).